# AWS RDS and Lambda question How to query a database and use data as variable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I'm currently trying to create a system where a AWS Lambda function accesses a  RDS database and query a column containing dates and search for a specific date and if it is found to pull data from the database to be used in the lambda function as a variable.

Apologies if this is a bit vague.O

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find tons of tutorials to do that online, but here are the main points:

- Your Lambda should be deployed in a VPC, and you attach a VPC security group to it.
- The SG attached to your RDS needs to allow your Lambda to access it.
- Your Lambda needs to use a MySQL/PSQL/... to query your RDS database.
- The credentials to access your DB should be passed to your Lambda function using environment variables and/or Systems Manager Parameter Store and/or Secrets Manager.
- In any cases, your DB_PASSWORD should never be passed in plain text.

Be careful of some Lambda limitation, specifically the 15mins timeout in case your query takes a long time to run.

Comment: Hello Thanks for the advice ill give it a go